# remove links from woocommerce category using a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, code-snippets, affiliate

I'm using the shortcode

```
[product_category category="jacuzzis" columns="3"]
```

to show some amazon affiliate products on my website. The issue is that I don't want the user going to the product page under my domain but instead going to the amazon affiliate link.

In order to do that I'm trying first eliminating the link on the products. I'm using this code

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 10 );
```

It should remove the open link tag and the close link tag, but the link is still working after adding the snippet.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I just change my theme on wordpress which was oceanwp to the default twenty twenty. Now the links are gone. Does anyone know why is this? and how to do it using oceanwp?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity` hook to add your custom button with ACF field. and just remove 'buy' button with CSS or another hook.